# Clojure- comparing a line with a string

Tags: clojure

```
    (def filename "dictionary2.txt")

    (defn check_word [filename word]
      (with-open [r (clojure.java.io/reader filename)]
        (doseq [line (line-seq r)]
          (if (compare line word)
            (println word)))))

    (check_word filename "wizard")
```

It prints "found" as many as the number of lines in the text file. Why is if statement always returning true? Word of "wizard" does exist in the dictionary file.

Comment: `compare` returns a number which always evaluates to `true` in boolean context.

Comment: @Lee identical? did not work either. How do you check?

Comment: compare returns -1, 0, or 1, depending on the lexicographic order of compared strings.. So when `s1 == s2 => (compare s1 s2) == 0`, and the minimal change to `(zero? (compare line word))` should fix that.. But i would rather go with simple `(= (clojure.string/trim line) word)`

Comment: @leetwinski thanks. it solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation the [compare function](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/compare) returns a negative number, zero, or a positive number depending on the order of its parameters. Numbers are considered [*truthy* values](http://blog.jayfields.com/2011/02/clojure-truthy-and-falsey.html), so they always make the *then* branch of a conditional expression execute. The only *falsey* values in Clojure are `nil` and `false`.

If you want to check that `line` equals `word` you can use just [equality](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/=) with `(= line word)`.